# Liferay service.xml foreign key many-to-many

Tags: service, entity, liferay, builder

Hello Liferay experts,

Please help me to create a `service.xml` in Liferay for the following scenario:

I have 2 tables

1. **`SystemUsed`**

   ```
   systemUsedId long
   name varchar
   ```
2. **`User_SystemUsed`**

   ```
   userId long        --> mapped to userId of User_ table
   systemUsedId long  --> mapped to  systemUsedId of SystemUsed table.<br>
   ```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create tables as follows:

```
<entity name="SystemUsed" local-service="true" remote-service="false"> 
    <column name="systemUsedId type="Long" />
    <column name="name" type="String"/>
</entity>
<entity name="User_SystemUsed" local-service="true" remote-service="false">  
    <column name="systemUsedId" type="SystemUsed" entity="SystemUsed" mapping-key="systemUsedId" />  
    <column name="userId" type="User" entity="User_" mapping-key="userid" />  
</entity>
```

I hope the user_ table is mapped correctly like that...